# Monitor primitive String declaration

Tags: javascript, string, node.js, primitive

Is there ANY way of monitoring primitive String declaration in NodeJS?
For example, when I do `"test";` is there any way of triggering a special event with `"test"` as a parameter?

Comment: Why do you need to do that? Because you can't but if we knew why you want to, we could probably find a way around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by *do "test;"*; but if you want to trigger an event whenever a variable is assigned a new value, no, there is no way to trigger an event for variable changes.

If you want to watch a variable, it is better to re-design your system to make a call instead of assigning a variable. Instead of doing:

```
running_mode = "test";
```

require

```
switch_mode("test");
```

and call whatever event handlers you want to trigger on this update.

If you really want to watch the value of a global variable, you can do it by checking the value once in every turn of the main loop:

```
function is_mode_changed() {
   if (running_mode=="test") event_handler();
   process.nextTick(is_mode_changed);
}
```

Once you call this function, it will continue running once each turn of the main loop. If it what you want to do is something like following a variable to do some specific tasks time to time, like following a global counter and doing some cleanup tasks everytime counter reaches 1000, this is a good way to do. If what you want to do something immediately after a variable is changed, it is not possible.

I hope I could understand your question correctly.

**UPDATE**

[I am adding this in regards to the comment below which rendered everything above unrelated to question because I had misunderstood it.]

As you mentioned yourself, a string literal like `"test"` is a *primitive value* which is not an object. So, it is handled by the interpreter in a way we cannot alter.

From Ecma-262:

> **4.3.2 primitive value**
>
> member of one of the types `Undefined`, `Null`, `Boolean`, `Number`, or `String` as defined in Clause 8
>
> **NOTE:** A primitive value is a datum that is represented directly at the lowest level of the language implementation.

*To prevent confusion, **Clause 8** is the section of standard on Types as listed above.*

Comment: That was not my question. The thing is, there is two way to declare a String : `"test"` will return a primitive value and `String("test")` will return an object. While `String("test")` calls the constructor of `String`, `"test"` doesn't call any constructor. I'd like to know if an event is fired each time a primitive value is constructed.

Answer (score 1):

Since you specified V8, and not per-spec-ECMAScript, you have more concrete options at your disposal. In the V8 API there is classes/templates or primitives that are separate from those of object wrappers for primitives. In order to be able to hook in a way to know when this actually happens would likely require modifying v8 in a custom manner, but it is doable.

http://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/branches/bleeding_edge/include/v8.h#1017

Also much of the action takes place in js itself. Perhaps not the very constructor itself, but everything that happens thereafter. String.prototype.toString/valueOf.

http://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/branches/bleeding_edge/src/string.js

Comment: This is not V8 API, it is the source code :p ...and of course everything is possible once you decide to modify anything that comes on your way, anything! When you modify V8 this way, it is not V8 anymore. When you modify the way primitives work, it is not JavaScript anymore... This is doable as making trains fly and planes ride on rails. You just need wings for one and steel wheels for the other... just joking, nothing serious. :)

Comment: Well given that: no. In fact there's no way to monitor any kind of literal constructor invocation, primitive, array, function, object. Literals are one of the few things that **no method exists** for gaining insight into. There's tricks for everything else, or almost everything.